# Message queues to trigger events for kafka and Redis from one service to other service

Tags: python, apache-kafka, redis, message-queue

I have two services which runs in python2 and python3. One will be socket service other would be general calculation service based on the data from socket.

I would like to communicate between one to other service via message queues before we emit any event to client.

Is there any existed feature for both redis and kafka to trigger events for each services ? so that we can create a pool over that and use pubsub or publish and consume methodology. I have gone through some of the documents but couldn't conclude on the approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka does not push events; your client will poll the broker for events in some loop/external trigger. Kafka Connect can be setup to read from Redis changes, which the consumer will pickup...

If you don't need a message queue, you can use standard socket server, Socket.IO, gRPC, etc which all will allow you to emit and receive true "service events" without managing external services.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm currently using socket.io for my project. so here socket service is communicating with external service via message queue. I need a bidirectional communication between these two services. Can there be producer and consumer in same server of different topics in kafka to make bidirectional ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73648007/does-kafka-to-support-bidirectional

Comment: Kafka is not bi-directional since brokers do not "push" events, as answered. Data only flows one way from producers or consumers with respect to the client application. You may want to look at gRPC for proper bi-directional communication without needing a message queue.