# Does Kafka to support bidirectional?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, gevent, kafka-python

I have two servers where bidirectional communication needs to be happened.

For kafka I have 2 topics 2 producers and 2 consumers. Trying to communicate server 1 to 2 with 1topic and 1 consumer and 1 producer and vice versa for the 2nd server.

**producer.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer
import gevent
import time
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
consumer = KafkaConsumer('game_events', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

def prod():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        producer.send('sockets', b'Hello  world') 
        producer.flush()
    

def cons():
    while True:
        game_server = consumer.__next__()
        print(game_server)


gevent.spawn(prod())
gevent.spawn(cons())
```

**Consumer.py**

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
import gevent
import time
consumer = KafkaConsumer('sockets', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

def cons():
    while(True):
        game_server = consumer.__next__()
        print(game_server)


def prod():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print("game_server")
        producer.send('game_events', b'Hello  Game Event') 
        producer.flush()

#for message in consumer:
#    print(message)



gevent.spawn(cons())
gevent.spawn(prod())
```

Here the consumer is just receiving the **sockets** topic message but not the topic **game_events**.  Is there any way to achieve this ? or Kafka doesn't support it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> producer.py
> consumer.py

Well, that's confusing. Both modules have producers and consumers....

---

You call `cons()`, which starts an infinite loop. If the loop ever ended, *that result* is passed into `gevent.spawn()`, and **only then** would `prod()` function run.

If you meant to start a Greenlet thread, you need to pass the function handle itself, which internally starts threads for those functions.

```
gevent.spawn(cons)
gevent.spawn(prod)
```

Also, rather than a while loop for the consumer, you should be able to have `for msg in consumer`, then you need to get `msg.value()`

---

You don't really need `gevent`.

Your producer could be a [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) and the consumer just a `Thread`. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#multi-threading

Comment: I was doing some test so gave filenames in that way. I was able to achieve the bidirectional with threading. In the above 2 files one must be in one server(python2) and the other must be on other server(python3). Any document of maintaining kafka connection pool for both python3 and python2  ?

Comment: `thread1 = threading.Thread(target=prod)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=cons)
thread2.start()`
Using these lines in both the files. able to get messages from both the files. Is it fine if i use this as two way communicator ?

Comment: If it works, then it's fine. Ideally, you upgrade both environments to use Python3 (I don't think `kafka-python` library supports Python2, or at least `pip` definitely doesn't anymore)